# ARIMA forecasting with quarterly dummies

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

My code:

```
library(fpp2)
library(lmtest)
y<- log(ts(filename[,"Y"], start=1964, frequency=4, end=2015))
Q1 <- ts(filename[,"Q1"], start=1964, frequency=4, end=2015)
Q2 <- ts(filename[,"Q2"], start=1964, frequency=4, end=2015)
Q3 <- ts(filename[,"Q3"], start=1964, frequency=4, end=2015)
Q4 <- ts(filename[,"Q4"], start=1964, frequency=4, end=2015)
qdummies <- cbind(Q1,Q2,Q3)

fit_y <- Arima(y, order=c(1,1,0), xreg=qdummies, method="ML"))
```

If I omit the *xreg=qdummies* portion, I can proceed to forecast the next 3 years via:

```
plot(forecast(y, model=fit_y, h=12))
```

However if I include the *xreg=qdummies* portion, when I forecast using the same command above, I get the following error:

```
Error in arima2(x, model, xreg = xreg, method = method) : 
No regressors provided
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Thank you.

I've tried to be as specific as I can (since I'm still learning).

**Also**, is there a way to show t-statistic and p-value when I want to evaluate my ARIMA specification? The Arima specification given above only ends up showing me the coefficient and s.e in row format, without the accompanying t-statistic and p-values. Currently, I am doing using the *lmtest* package via:

```
coeftest(y)
```

However, that only gives me asymptotic z values.

Thank you!